# SceneKit – Transition between textures

Tags: ios, image, colors, textures, scenekit

## The Basics:

I have many SCNNodes that need to change color all at once. They go from green to blue. Currently, I have two separate images for each of the nodes (one green and the other blue), and I'm trying to switch the image for all of the nodes. Here's my code:

```
let blueTubeTexture = UIImage(named: "BlueTubeTexture")
self.tube1.geometry!.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents = blueTubeTexture
```

Basically, I have many global nodes (tube1, tube2, tube3, etc.) that all share the same geometry. Since they share the same geometry, changing one node's material changes all of them at once.

---

## The Problem:

The only problem with this solution is that changing even one texture slows down the app. It glitches when I try to change the texture of ***one*** tube. But changing all of them at once results in a crash.

---

## What Am I Asking For?

Is changing the texture in this way inefficient? If changing only one image puts a lot of stress on the CPU, then maybe it's not a good solution. Is there a better way to change the color of the image like this?

Answer (score 0):

looks like a memory issue. How big are these maps? If you try to load to many images in memory your app will be killed by the system. Have you tried profiling it?

Also note that the following will also work and will save the allocation of an `UIImage`:

```
diffuse.contents = "BlueTubeTexture"
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. As far as the size of the maps, there are many images, each fairly large. Do you think that it would be more efficient if I put them into atlases rather than 1x, 2x, and 3x?

Comment: I'm not sure asset catalogs help for textures applied to models. Their size on screen depends on close you are to the object, not the king of device you have. Just make sure that your images are of the correct size. Small when their appear small on scree, larger when they appear bigger on screen.